# angular material 2 md-autocomplete dynamic name

Tags: angular-material2

In the documentation explains that you have to create a md-autocomplete like that:

```
<md-form-field>
    <input type="text" mdInput [formControl]="myControl" [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
</md-form-field>
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
   <md-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
   </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Is there is any way to generate the #auto on runtime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you expand on your use case?

Comment: I would like to creat autocomplete depends on a backend response (2, 3, ...). If all of have the #auto atribute when I change a value change to all. I think for each autocomplet I have to define a especial tag. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to wrap it in an `*ngFor` like this so that your template variable's scope is limited to only that `for loop` iteration,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let autocomplete of autocompletes">

  <!-- Input -->
  <md-form-field>
    <input type="text"
        mdInput
        [formControl]="autocomplete.control"
        [placeholder]="autocomplete.placeholder"
        [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
  </md-form-field>

  <!-- Autocomplete -->
  <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let option of autocomplete.options" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>

</ng-container>
```

```
autocompletes = [
  { placeholder: 'Sample 1', options: [1, 2, 3], control: new FormControl() },
  { placeholder: 'Sample 2', options: [3, 4, 5], control: new FormControl() },
  { placeholder: 'Sample 3', options: [6, 7, 8], control: new FormControl() },
];
```

See this [EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta11-qjkvkc).